# Is it possible to change the Hashing algorithm in django_auth?

Tags: django, django-authentication

I have a running wiki with users. Now I want to write an app in Django to do a specific task.

I have to use my "old" users/groups database (which has a different hashing algorithm for passwords then django_auth) and sync it every now and then since my users already have a login which has to be the same everywhere.

I want to use django_auth as well.

**Is it possible to change the Hashing algorithm in django_auth?**

so that django auth uses a function I write to check whether the password inserted is right or wrong.

Thanks in advance, Senad. =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quoting [How Django stores passwords](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/passwords/#how-django-stores-passwords) docs:

> Django chooses the algorithm to use by consulting the PASSWORD_HASHERS setting. This is a list of hashing algorithm classes that this Django installation supports. The first entry in this list (that is, settings.PASSWORD_HASHERS[0]) will be used to store passwords, and all the other entries are valid hashers that can be used to check existing passwords. This means that if you want to use a different algorithm, you’ll need to modify PASSWORD_HASHERS to list your preferred algorithm first in the list.

You can write your custom one, just copy paste a hasher from https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/hashers.py, make your customizations and add to settings:

```
PASSWORD_HASHERS = [
    'myApp.myUtils.CesarPasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2SHA1PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.Argon2PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.BCryptSHA256PasswordHasher',
]
```

Comment: i would vote your comment up but i am not allowed yet =) have a nice day

Comment: Link was broken.

Comment: hi @shaikmoeed, thanks, was an answer from '12! Updated.

Comment: Thanks for updating. If I'm using `django_auth_ldap` library, will these hashers applicable to LDAP logins? Can you please look into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60223293/8353711) in your free time?

Answer (score 1):

You can write a [custom authentication backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/auth/#other-authentication-sources) that includes its own `authenticate` function to check passwords according to your custom hash. Of course, you'll need some way of distinguishing between the different types of users.

Comment: what do you mean by "the different types of users" ?

Comment: I understood you to mean that you had some users for whom you wanted to use the existing django-auth hashing.

Comment: nope, i want to use the existing wiki-database users and groups. sync that when required (e.g. login failed).

thanks anyways :)

Comment: Cool, well just ignore that bit of my answer - the custom authentication backend is still the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible. See [django-bcyrpt](https://github.com/dwaiter/django-bcrypt) for an example. It will be easier to change in Django 1.4: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.4/#improved-password-hashing